# Unable to load xForm due to XFormsLinkException

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am trying to load an xForm into my java application. It is working fine in tomcat environment but giving the below exception in websphere. Please help.

```
[7/10/13 2:00:59:865 CST] 0000001e Container     W org.chiba.xml.xforms.Container handleEventException handle event exception: org.chiba.xml.xforms.exception.XFormsLinkException kept for rethrowal after dispatch() has finished
[7/10/13 2:00:59:866 CST] 0000001e Container     W org.chiba.xml.xforms.Container handleEventException XForms Error: uri resolution failed
[7/10/13 2:00:59:867 CST] 0000001e XFormsElement E org.chiba.xml.xforms.core.Model performDefault [xforms:model:common-model] link exception: /contentdm/servlet/edms.do?action=DB_MANAGE_XFORM_REQUEST&subaction=getDataXML&token=uKNjB4J8upr6YfsWhtB5G8z&taskId=119
[7/10/13 2:00:59:868 CST] 0000001e Container     E org.chiba.xml.xforms.Container dispatch dispatch: exception during event flow
                                 org.chiba.xml.xforms.exception.XFormsLinkException: uri resolution failed
    at org.chiba.xml.xforms.core.Instance.getInitiallInstance(Instance.java:701)
    at org.chiba.xml.xforms.core.Instance.init(Instance.java:157)
    at org.chiba.xml.xforms.core.Model.createInstanceObject(Model.java:868)
    at org.chiba.xml.xforms.core.Model.modelConstruct(Model.java:852)
    at org.chiba.xml.xforms.core.Model.performDefault(Model.java:748)
    at org.chiba.xml.events.impl.DefaultXMLEventService.dispatch(DefaultXMLEventService.java:286)
    at org.chiba.xml.xforms.Container.dispatch(Container.java:497)
    at org.chiba.xml.xforms.Container.dispatch(Container.java:475)
    at org.chiba.xml.xforms.Container.initModels(Container.java:716)
    at org.chiba.xml.xforms.Container.init(Container.java:330)
    at org.chiba.xml.xforms.ChibaBean.init(ChibaBean.java:421)
    at org.chiba.web.WebAdapter.init(WebAdapter.java:199)
    at org.chiba.web.flux.FluxAdapter.init(FluxAdapter.java:152)
    at org.chiba.web.session.impl.XFormsSessionBase.init(XFormsSessionBase.java:305)
    at org.chiba.web.filter.XFormsFilter.doFilter(XFormsFilter.java:141)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:997)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.FileServletWrapper.handleRequest(FileServletWrapper.java:533)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.StaticFileServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(StaticFileServletWrapperImpl.java:135)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:930)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3944)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.ard.channel.ARDChannelConnLink.handleDiscrimination(ARDChannelConnLink.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.ard.channel.ARDChannelConnLink.ready(ARDChannelConnLink.java:93)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1049)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:643)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1646)
Caused by: org.chiba.xml.xforms.exception.XFormsException: no uri resolver registered for '/contentdm/servlet/edms.do?action=DB_MANAGE_XFORM_REQUEST&subaction=getDataXML&token=uKNjB4J8upr6YfsWhtB5G8z&taskId=119'
    at org.chiba.xml.xforms.connector.DefaultConnectorFactory.createURIResolver(DefaultConnectorFactory.java:180)
    at org.chiba.xml.xforms.core.Instance.getInitiallInstance(Instance.java:698)
    ... 44 more
```

Comment: forgot to add my name

Answer (score 0):

As the [XForms Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms/#evt-linkException) states, the he xforms-link-exception Event is:

> Dispatched as an indication of: a failure to traverse or process the result of a link in a situation critical to form processing, such as schema or instance initialization.

It looks like `/contentdm/servlet/edms.do(...)` doesn't respond appropriately in your Websphere environment.  It may be that it responds with something the XForms processor can't handle, or that it doesn't respond at all.